# Need script to move multiple rows and columns over one column when date changes in b4

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // Check if the edited cell is B4
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("MASTER");
  if (sheet.getName() == "MASTER" && e.range.getA1Notation() == "B4") {
    // Move columns C5:OG22 to the left
    var firstColumn = sheet.getRange("C5:OG22").getColumn();
    sheet.insertColumnsBefore(firstColumn);
  }
}
```

I’m not understanding why this wont work.  I can’t test it in the editor because it’s looking for a change that it can’t see so it throws an error

Comment: Can I ask you about the details of `this wont work`? And, can I ask you about the details of your expected result? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: I load it into google apps script and save the I go to b4 and change the date and nothing happens.  I expect that at every night cell b4 will change the date automatically( I have it so that from b4og4 all the dates shift one column left.  So I want the script to notice the change in b4 then move the values I have in c5:og22 over one column so that the info corresponds to the date in row 4

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you could forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Always include all relevant details, like the error message in your question. (You can [edit] it, no need to add comments, btw.) See also [ask].